# How to display SharedAssemblyInfo.cs details in footer

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get the details on my SharedAssemblyInfo.cs and display the details on my page footer?

Here are the details of the SharedAssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using VersionInfo;
// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("nhoyti and company")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("nhoyti")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("nhoyti and company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("nhoyti")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2019")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
// Database version Number
[assembly: AssemblyDatabaseVersion(56)]
// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("c20aead6-2892-40c5-8be4-8a90ed87bdcc")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.6.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.6.1.0")]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What "page"? Are we talking about ASP.NET? You will probably want to use the [Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=netframework-4.7.2) class. ( See example inside linked docu)

Comment: Yes. ASP.NET. an HTML page

Comment: I added the ASP.NET tag, so people from that field will be more likely to see the question.

Comment: I had the same problem few years ago and gave up in the end. SharedAssemblyInfo is used only during compile time for DLL stamping. It is not used during run time (which seems to be your case).